# multidimensional array returns bad results with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a php class that interacts with mysql database and then fetches an array as a result.

```
$res = $db->getResult(); // $res is an array
```

I use it with print_r :

```
print_r($res);
```

and it outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => Mohamed
            [lastname] => Kadri
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [firstname] => Slim
            [lastname] => Nejmaoui
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [firstname] => Sameh
            [lastname] => Chraiti
        )
```

And with foreach:

```
foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br />';
}
```

it outputs this:

```
1 Mohamed Kadri
2 Slim Nejmaoui
3 Sameh Chraiti
```

but when there is only one row, it shows this:

```
1 1 1
M M M    
K K K
```

(1 is the id, M is the first letter in the firstname and K is the first letter in the lastname).

So maybe when there is more than one row the class generates a multidimensional array and the foreach will work on it, and when there is only one row it generates a simple array that will be treated as a multidimensional array by this exact foreach.

So should I make a condition to process one of two types of foreach?

Thanks.

Comment: Enable the reporting of all types of errors, so PHP tells you about potential issues in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently your db object return a single array when you have only one result somthing like that:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [firstname] => Slim
    [lastname] => Nejmaoui
)
```

you can test first input and if this is not an array don't loop thrue the foreach else do a foreach

```
if( is_array(current($res)) ){
  // do the foreach...
}else{
  echo $res['id'] . ' ' . $res['firstname'] . ' ' . $res['lastname'] . '<br />';
}
```

I think you should change your db class to always return a nested array even on single row result to keep your results consistents.

Comment: ok here it works well, but if I have a zero results array, it gets a error telling that these indexes (id, firstname, lastname) are undefined. so how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it looks like that's exactly what's happening. Most likely, `$db->getResult()` returns the resulting row as an array (not sub-arrays within the result) when there is only one row returned from the query. So, you'll need to detect if there are nested arrays and handle appropriately:

```
if (isset($res[0]) && is_array($res[0])){
    foreach ($res as $row) {
        echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br />';
    }
}else{
    echo $res['id'] . ' ' . $res['firstname'] . ' ' . $res['lastname'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: here it works but it returns an error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\www\test\index.php on line 51 (which is the first line of your code "if ($res[0]){")

Comment: you should better to test if current($res) is an array or a string, the error is because in case of single result you don't have a $res[0] setted, you may also just change the if($res[0]) by if(isset($res[0])).

Comment: You're both correct - that is just my shorthand to test if variables are there, but it's not technically correct. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CodeIgniter? Because it looks like you are. In CodeIgniter, when there is only one result, it only returns one array.

My suggestion? Create a support function (`do_something_with_row` below) and then call it conditionally:

```
if(count($res) > 1)
{
    foreach($res as $row)
    {
        do_something_with_a_row($row);
    }
}
else
{
    do_something_with_a_row($res);
}
```

Comment: How so? What are you getting and what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over one result-row in the case that is unclear to you.

What happens unnoticed to you is that `$row` then contains only scalar values:

1. `1` (int)
2. `Mohamed` (string)
3. `KadriK` (string)

This is the contents for `$row` already per each iteration (1-3).

These values are getting accessed with the [substring access syntax](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.substr) that looks exactly like an array, making use of square brackets.

As all indezies `'id'`, `'firstname'` and `'firstname'` are interpreted as constants which are all undefined and result in `0`, you're actually accessing the first character/byte in the string: `1`, `M` and `K`.

With a newer version of PHP the `1` would not even be returned.

**Now the important part: If you develop or you look for errors, enable the logging of notices.** They warn you about such things:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant Kadri - assumed 'Kadri' in ...
```

A quick setup can be done by adding this:

```
  error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```